# How do I separate multiple values such as '1.1.1.1.2.1' , '1.1.1.1.2.2', etc... to get each column?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Here is what I'm trying to work with.

```
SELECT
CBS
FROM HRD
ORDER BY CBS
```

And it would be ideal to get thes Levels, as I currently only get the `CBS` column.

```
L1     L2     L3      L4      ETC....   CBS
1      1.1    1.1.1   1.1.1.1           1.1.1.1.2.1
1      1.1    1.1.1   1.1.1.1           1.1.1.1.2.2
1      1.1    1.1.1   1.1.1.1           1.1.1.1.2.3
1      1.1    1.1.1   1.1.1.1           1.1.1.1.2.4
1      1.2    1.2.1   1.2.1.1           1.2.1.1.2.1
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 1):

If the CBS field is fixed length this is pretty easy with `SUBSTRING`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8d0fa/1)**

```
SELECT substring(cbs, 1, 1) as L1,
  substring(cbs, 1, 3) AS L2,
  substring(cbs, 1, 5) AS L3, 
  substring(cbs, 1, 7) AS L4,
  substring(cbs, 1, 9) AS L5,
  substring(cbs, 1, 11) AS L6, 
  CBS
FROM HRD
ORDER BY CBS
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pretty solution, but it works. You can accomplish this with [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). I wrote it this way assuming that you are parsing a string of unknown length and there may be more than one number between period characters.

By stacking CHARINDEX and adding 1 to the previous value you always find the next position of '.' regardless of how many numbers are between them.

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(CBS, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CBS)) as L1,
SUBSTRING(CBS, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS) + 1)) as L2,
SUBSTRING(CBS, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS) + 1) + 1)) as L3,
SUBSTRING(CBS, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS) + 1) + 1) + 1)) as L4,
SUBSTRING(CBS, 0, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS, CHARINDEX('.', CBS) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1)) as L5,
CBS
FROM HRD
ORDER BY CBS
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries always result in a before-known number of columns. So you need to know the maximum number of levels when writing the query.

Then it depends on your dbms what it offers to find the point and get a sub-string. Is it always just one digit for each level? That would make things easier, because you would simply get the first, third, fifth, and so on, character.

Oracle example with a maximum of four levels. Substr gives you the string parts, i.e. the digits. If the string is shorter, it results in NULL for that column.

```
select
  substr(cbs,1,1) as l1,
  substr(cbs,3,1) as l2,
  substr(cbs,5,1) as l3,
  substr(cbs,7,1) as l4
from hrd
order by cbs;
```

EDIT: Here is an Oracle example for the case that a level can have more than one digit:

```
select
  regexp_substr(cbs, '[^.]+', 1, 1) as l1,
  regexp_substr(cbs, '[^.]+', 1, 2) as l2,
  regexp_substr(cbs, '[^.]+', 1, 3) as l3,
  regexp_substr(cbs, '[^.]+', 1, 4) as l4
from hrd
order by cbs;
```